# Deploying changes only to Firebase helper functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my firebase functions files I have two types of functions:

1. Exported functions that will be triggered by Firestore and HTTPS Callable functions. (These are stored in multiple files, each file imported into my index.ts file)
2. Helper functions that are used in the exported functions.

These are structured like this:

- /functions/src/index.ts
- /functions/src/firestoreTriggers.ts
- /functions/src/callables.ts
- /functions/src/helpers.ts

The index.ts file imports the firestoreTriggers and callables files.
The firestoreTriggers and Callables files import specific functions from the helpers.ts file, when needed.

Some of these helper functions are used across multiple exported functions (and files), so cannot be contained within an exported function.

Is it possible to deploy changes to only specific helper functions?

Currently I need to run    `firebase deploy --only functions`
to deploy changes to the functions in my helpers.ts file.

I imagine it wouldn't be a good idea to export all of my functions as callable functions, just so they can be updated separately.

Thank you!

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you can export one function or group them together

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you want to group them together

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'    
const functionBuilder = functions.region(REGION)

export const helperFunctions = {
    // Add all helper functions here and deploy them all at once
    // Not sure if youre using onRequest or onCall etc
    functionOneName: functionBuilder.https.onRequest(functionOneImportedFunction),
    functionTwoName: functionBuilder.https.onRequest(functionTwoImportedFunction),
}
```

Then from the command line

```
firebase deploy --only functions:helperFunctions
```

For a single function

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'    
const functionBuilder = functions.region(REGION)
export const functionName = functionBuilder.https.onRequest(functionOneImportedFunction)
```

Then from the command line

```
firebase deploy --only functions:functionName
```

Comment: Thank you @omeanwell I will try this as soon as possible to test it, then upvote if it works. Sorry for the delayed response!

Comment: No worries! You can mark it as the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: I got here bc of the same issue: I'm unable to deploy helper functions that are used in the exported trigger functions. In my case these aren't trigger functions, just reusable js functions (and that seems to be the case for OP as well, since the trigger functions are OP's item #1). I've not been able to make this work and I suspect it's bc they aren't trigger functions.

Comment: I am still having the same problem, @agileMike you are correct with your comment. Did you find a way around this?

Comment: @ChrisJacobs honestly I've worked on so many other things since then I don't remember what I did. I can tell you I've been following the patterns documented here and it has helped a lot. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions